# How to convert a list of Lat/Long to a String array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps

I have a list of Lat/Long `List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();` and I add elements to it when I click on the map (I'm using google map v2) using `points.add(latLng);`. My objective is to draw lines between the points using:

```
 map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(x, y), new LatLng(x1, y1)).
 width(5).color(Color.BLUE));
```

The problem is I don't know how to convert a list of Lat/long to a `String[]`, So that I can split each index to lat and long and traverse the array, drawing lines using the method above. How do i achieve that?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnClose:
            this.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btnDeleteFile:
            deleteFile();
            break;
        case R.id.btnDrawLines:
            drawLines(latLng);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    drawLines(latLng);
    drawIcons(latLng);
    try {
        savePositions(latLng);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void drawLines(LatLng latLng) {

    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(latLng);
}
```

Comment: What `String` do you expect?  What would the strings corresponding to a `LatLng` look like?

Comment: Can you explain in more details why you want to convert to a `String[]`?

Comment: is it possible to do  this from points list: new LatLng(points.get(i).latitude, points.get(i).lontitude)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to convert to a `String[]`. If you want to just draw a line between two points you could try something like the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++) {
        LatLng currentPoint = points.get(i);
        LatLng nextPoint = points.get(i+1);
        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(currentPoint, nextPoint)).
                width(5).color(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Or looking at the [PolyLineOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html) docs it seems like you should be able to pass the entire list of points using:

```
new PolyLineOptions().addAll(points)
```

Edit:

After looking at your code it seems that you are not keeping track of your points consider moving your list of points to be a field.

Here is a basic example of how you could keep track of all the points and continue to draw more as you click more on the map:

```
 public class YourClass {

    List<LatLong> points;

    public YourClass() {
        points = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void drawLines(LatLng latLng) {
       points.add(latLng);
       map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(points).
                width(5).color(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

Comment: i have a method: drawLine(latLng) inside the onMapclick(LatLng latLng) and the implementation is: private void drawLine(LatLng latLng) { List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();  points.add(latLng); ...and your suggestion but it dosen't work!

Comment: Can you post more of you code so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Every time that you call drawLines you are creating a new List and only adding 1 point to the list. You probably need to have the list of points accumulate with each call to drawLines. Maybe have the list be a field in the class if it won't ever be accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: okay. But how to save each click i do on the map to an arrayList?

Comment: Thanks. I have understood much better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you access the latlong's values directly? They're `public final doubles`, and should be accessible.

Eg:

```
LatLng p = new LatLng(x, y); // if you have this point

// you can do this and get the values
String pLat = p.latitude.toString();
String pLong = p.longitude.toString();
// now you can store pLat and pLong in an array of lats and longs.
```

So if you have an arraylist of points, and an arraylist of lats, and an arraylist of longs

```
for (LatLng p : points) {
    // get values and store them
    listOfLats.add(p.latitude.toString());
    listOfLongs.add(p.latitude.toString());
}
```

Now that you have those stored (in pairs), you can access them using the same index i for different points.

Although TBH, I don't know what is wrong with your current method - it seems to be a supported method, and you don't need to get a string value since the function(s) itself actually takes a LatLng obj...

**EDIT: That being said, you can try:**

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(points).width(5).color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: I have just an array of points coming from a clicked map like: List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>(); and points.add(latLng);

Comment: i tried your suggestion like this:  
i have a method: drawLine(latLng) inside the onMapclick(LatLng latLng) and the implementation is: private void drawLine(LatLng latLng) { List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>(); points.add(latLng); ...and your suggestion but it dosen't work!

Comment: Are you trying to add a line everytime you click or a line after you click all the points?

Comment: I posted more methods. i click on the map then i click a button to draw the lines. Each time i click a point is added to the list..i hope so!

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to convert it to strings, you can just convert the List into an array:

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(points.toArray(new LatLng[points.size()])).width(5).color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: i have posted more methods

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for. If your goal is to simply draw a line every time they click there is no reason to use a polyline, simply keep track of the last point they clicked on and draw a single line between that point and the new point. If your goal is to keep track of all the points and draw them as a polyline you can simply convert the List of LatLng to an array, it will work as is for the add method.

Comment: this is the whole problem. how to convert a list of LatLng to an array?